# Having troubles pushing into an array which is a property of an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array called "players" which stores all the players, each element of this array contains each individual player stored as an object, and this player object contains a property called "time" which in it of itself is an array. When ever I try to push an integer into this time array, I get a "time.push() is not a function" error.

```
players[data.num].time.push(uptime());
```

what I am attempting here is `array[index].array.push()`

This array is undefined and is declared like `this.time = [];`
The player objects were made by constructor function as well.

Here are the other arrays I mentioned before;

```
var players = [];
players.push(new Player(0,0,true));
```

Player() is a constructor function that contains `this.time = [];`

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of this array?

Comment: Is players[data.num].time initialized?

Comment: console.log(players[data.num].time); what do you see?

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. All we can do is guess based on your written description.

Comment: it is not initiallized, no.

Comment: You need to have initially `players = [ {time: [], ...}, ... ]` to be able to use `push`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, I understand how to access it, this question is asking of how to write it out, but I already understand the syntax

Comment: So you don't have anywhere `var players = [];`?

Comment: yes the player array is a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very stupid mistake.

```
this.time = [];
```

and just a few lines later...

```
this.time = 0;
```

I created the former this.time = 0; for animation, I forgot about it when making this array and as you know, you cannot push into and int variable.

Sorry for causing all the trouble...

Answer (score 0):

I base my answer upon that you have an array of objects with another array in each object. Then this should work.

```
var objs = [{array:[]},{array:[]},{array:[]}]

objs[0].array.push("test");

console.log(objs)
```

http://jsbin.com/romubeyoyu/edit?js,console

Comment: I am doing this though, but does it make a difference that the player object I discussed before was made by a constructor function?

Comment: @Canatron Could you share more of your code? Is there any async actions perhaps?

Comment: what is an asynchronus action?